# Get SelectedItems in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've a problem with my selected items recuperation in my datagrid.

In my xaml file, I've this :

```
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=technicalAlarmDatagrid}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Then, in my ViewModel, I've the binding Command like this :

```
        public ICommand SelectionChanged
        {
            get
            {
                if (_selectionChangedCommand == null)
                    _selectionChangedCommand = CreateCommand<object>(OnSelectionChanged);
                return _selectionChangedCommand;
            }
        }

        private void OnSelectionChanged(object parameter)
        {
            ...
        }
```

Now, my problem is :
In my datagrid, if I just have one item, the selectionChanged event doesn't work. But if I have more than one item, so, my event works.

Do you have any idea in order to solve my problem ?
Thank a lot !

Comment: Is the selectionchanged event based on a mouse click on a row?

Comment: Did you make a decision not to use [the SelectedCellsChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcellschanged(v=vs.110).aspx)? Forgive me if the question seems obnoxious; you can't always tell on here if people are experienced or not.

Comment: SelectedItems.Index needs to be -1 on loaded this will enable SelectionChanged to fire even if only 1 record

Answer (score 0):

In your XAML Code add attribute `SelectedIndex="-1"`

```
<DataGrid SelectedIndex="-1" SelectionChanged="DataGridSelectionChanged" ...>
  ...
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: The selectedIndex doesn't change anything... I've already the same problem